# How to invert many-to-many relationship?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a compacted Kafka topic that is a stream of entities have the latest representation of that entity in a many-to-many relationship that I'd like to invert.

An example would be a topic of `Author` objects where the topic key is the `Author.id` (AAA) and the value is an array of `Book' identifier values:

```
"AAA" -> {"books": [456]}
```

When an `Author` writes a new `Book` with an ID of `333`, a new event with the same key is written to the stream with the updated list of books:

```
"AAA" -> {"books": [456, 333]}
```

It is also possible that a `Book` had multiple `Authors` so that same `Book` identifier could appear in another event:

```
"BBB" -> {"books": [333, 555]}
```

I'd like to invert this using kafka streams into a stream of `Books -> [Author]`, so the above events would result in something like:

```
456 -> {"authors": ["AAA"]}
333 -> {"authors": ["AAA", "BBB"]}
555 -> {"authors": ["BBB"]}
```

When I start my app up again, I want the state to be restored such that if I read in another `Author` record it will invert the relationship appropriatley. So this:

```
"CCC" -> {"books": [555]}
```

would know that `"BBB"` was also an `Author` and would emit the updated event:

```
555 -> {"authors": ["BBB", "CCC"]}
```

I've been eyeing the `GlobalKTable` which reads in the full topic state locally, but can't figure out how to get it to invert the relationship and aggregate the values together.

If I could, I think I could join that `GlobalKTable` with a stream of the events and get the full list of `Author`s for each `Book`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use `GlobakKTable` to achieve your requirement.
In Kafka Streams, internal data redistribution caused by changing key occurs automatically. For example :

```
orgKStream
  .flatMapValues(books -> getBookList) (1)
  .map((k,v) -> new KeyValue<>(v, k))  (2)
  .groupByKey()                        (3)
  .aggregate(//aggregate author list ) (4)
  .toStream(// sink topic)             (5)
```

(1) will change your original topic like below.

```
<before>
"AAA" -> {"books": [456, 333]}
"BBB" -> {"books": [333, 555]}
<after>
"AAA" -> 456
"AAA" -> 333
"BBB" -> 333
"BBB" -> 555
```

(2) will replace the key with the value.

```
<after>
456 -> "AAA"
333 -> "AAA"
333 -> "BBB" 
555 -> "BBB"
```

(3) and (4) will aggregate and generate KTable (and state store)

```
<after>
456 -> {"authors": ["AAA"]}
333 -> {"authors": ["AAA", "BBB"]}
555 -> {"authors": ["BBB"]}
```

(5) will write whole records in the table into the given topic.

Now, you have a new topic that contains book as key and author list as values. If you want to have the whole result in one place, now just create GlobalKTable like below.

```
StreamsBuilder.globalTable(<sink topic>)
```

If (2) is called (map) and then (3) is called (groupByKey), internal data redistribution via repartition topic will occur. It means that all record that has same book id as a key will be published into the same partition of internal repartition topic. As a result, you will not lose any data for your aggregation.